# How to use SQL Like Operator in IBatis 2?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

Could somebody explain to me, how it is possoble to use the SQL Like operator in IBatis 2?

I want to execute some SQL code like this (I want to search something in columnA, which will be started with letter H):

```
SELECT table1.columnA,
       table1.columnB          
FROM   table1
WHERE  table1.columnA LIKE H%
```

I have tried this IBatis code, but it doesn´t work (I use an oracle database) :

```
<select id="selectExecuting" resultMap="myOenResultmap" parameterClass="java.util.Map">
    SELECT table1.columnA,
           table1.columnB          
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  table1.columnA LIKE '%$H$%'
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Like operator in iBatis**

Concatinate the '%' in sql.

```
<select id="getEmpByFName">
    select * from emp where first_name like '%' || #value# || '%'
</select>
```

[Source](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2009/09/ibatis-sql-with-dynamic-like-operator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NAME like #text# || '%'

Comment: Use this '%' + #{text} + '%'

Comment: this doesn´t work again: WHERE  pmg.modul LIKE '%$P$%' , I get this error message: Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '0', will now try the fallback translator

Comment: We are using ibatis 2 and #value# works for me  http://solitude.vkps.co.uk/Archives/2006/11/19/iBatisAndLike/

Comment: Now i get this error message (but I only have 4 datasets in my database, if I searched manually): SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Error: executeQueryForObject returned too many results.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error: executeQueryForObject returned too many results.

Comment: I have written WHERE table1.columnA  LIKE '%' || #searchedLetter# || '%' and searchedLetter is a key in my java map with the value P

Comment: Do you any other ideas? What could be the problem?